# Can anyone give me an example of a seperator used in table style in views

Tags: views, theming

I am not sure what seperator does. I basically want view of the 
node:title, and the node body in the same column of a table. How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

Dunno about drupal 7 but in in 6 youd go to your View, then View Style, select table, click on the wee wheel for options,  and then select which coloum you want your fields in.